# Is it possible to require modules from an embedded server-side resource (.axd)?

Tags: asp.net, requirejs, scriptresource.axd

I am using requireJS in a pretty standard configuration with server-side files (require modules).  I would like to embed my AMD modules in a server-side resource DLL and make them available via scriptresource.axd or something similar.

Is this possible without writing a custom requireJS plugin?